# Jasmine app vs YouTube App

Tags: ios, xcode, youtube-api, gdata-api

I am making an iOS app which displays youtube video from selected channels and playlists on a `UITableView`. When a cell is tapped the video is played on a `UIWebView`.

The app will asynchronously download the thumbnail and will cache the image to make sure the same image is not downloaded more then once. (cached in Core Data)

But I still feel the Jasmine app is faster at loading content, it's even faster than the YouTube app. How would Jasmine load content faster than googles Youtube app?

What can I do to load data faster?

Comment: Without seeing your implementation, all we can do is make general suggestions which will ultimately be unhelpful to you.

Comment: Loading the video in a `UIWebview` is slower than loading its mp4 in an `MPMoviePlayerController`, that's why Jasmine is faster than yours, but for me, Jasmine isn't faster than YouTube, they load in about the same speed.